# atom packages, clojurescript, google closure and dependency management

Tags: clojurescript, google-closure-library, atom-editor

I'm writing some atom (the editor) package with ClojureScript. And i faced dependency load issue.

When compiled ClojureScript produces file like this (main.js):

```
goog.addDependency("base.js", ['goog'], []);
goog.addDependency("../cljs/core.js", ['cljs.core'], ...)
goog.addDependency("../clojure/browser/event.js", ...)
```

Obviously, ClojureScript heavily depends on Google Closure dependency management.

But, to be able to use Google Closure i need to include goog/base.js file.

The only way that i found is to add to goog/base.js:

```
module.exports = goog
```

and add to main.js:

```
require('./goog/base.js')
```

This is very bad approach, because these files are generated - so they can be overridden.

Also, release compilation will not include these lines.

The question is how can i use both these dependency systems?

Or is it possible to use ClojureScript w/o Google Closure?

Please advice, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set your ClojureScript `:optimizations` to something other than `:none` (e.g., `:whitespace`) then the resulting `.js` file will include the Google Closure code inlined and you won't have to reference it separately.

(Note that this means you might not be able to use a `main` function in your ClojureScript code, but you can just put a call to your `main` function somewhere at the toplevel.)